# ReactJS - Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive

Tags: css, reactjs, security, inline-styles

I get the following error in the browser inspector (Chrome, Brave, Safari) when I load my ReactJS project in Production:

```
Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src-elem 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-TMIFk5ZjGNpczjRE6YVaBrPXVNzANj9JRK+w2bh9TX8='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

I used the below command to build the ReactJS project (it solves the inline script issue, but not the inline style):

```
INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false npm run build
```

This is the CSP policy part referring to the style:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; style-src-elem 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com; ..."
```

I believe the problem happens during the build phase, when React generates chunk files (with names such as '*2.3c013fe3.chunk.js*') and embeds inline style within the code, although I don't use inline style anywhere in my source code. All styles are contained in fileX.module.css and imported in the tsx files, like this example:

Example.tsx

```
import styles from './Example.module.css';

const Example = () => (
    <div className={styles.container}>
        Hello world
    </div>
);
```

Example.module.css

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
```

If the auto-generated chunk files are the problem, I don't see how to solve this issue with **hash** or **nonce** alternatives, since React will always generate these inline styles. On the other hand, I assume **unsafe-inline** is not an option, since this essentially makes the CSP useless.

Any suggestion either on the CSP directives or React settings to solve this issue? (I read all similar Q&A but none of them refers to this specific problem with React)

Comment: If you find any way to resolve this, i'll be interested to know how you did...

Comment: @Fieuxcédric Unfortunately I didn't get any reply on this and didn't manage to get it solved, so same error keeps showing in the inspector :/  Perhaps in future versions of React.js this might be addressed...

Comment: @SergiJuanati Did you find anything? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @chetan sadly, it remains unanswered.